# JQuery not detecting dynamically added Anchor Tag with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to work on a page that is loading a lot of stuff from a database using various `PHP` files. In order to do this I am using `JQuery` to detect when particular events happen and I then make an `AJAX` request to the required `PHP` file which will output the required contents.

It has been working very well but I've run into a bit of an issue. Basically When the user changes the value in the `select` menu it generates 3 new `select` menus each with a particular link associated to them. The idea being that they can click on this link to `Add Tags`.

Here's the problem, for some reason my `JQuery` is not detecting the newly added anchor tags and so my `click` event is not being handled.

I'm wondering if anyone could tell me a workaround to this, or perhaps if I'm even doing it correctly. I'd appreciate any help.

This is my `html` when the page first loads:

```
<p>
<select style="width:300px" name="comp" id="comp">
  <option value="0">Select an item...</option>
  <option value="1">test</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="comp_add">Add Tag</a>
</p>
```

This is the `JQuery` that is executed when the dropdown changes:

```
$('#comp').change(function() {
    var companyId = $(this).val();
    $('#compresult').load('pages/ajax/tag_manager_dropdowns.php',{test:companyId});
    $('#tag_results').load('pages/ajax/query_tags.php', {'query':"A"});
});
```

This is the `tag_manager_dropdowns.php` file:

```
$company_id = $_POST['test']; //Get the Company ID.

//Work out the Type.
$company = new DirectoryCompany($company_id);
$type = $company->getDirectoryCompanyType()->getName();

//All - Contacts
$output .=  "<p>".SelectBuilder::getDirectoryCompanyStaff("comp_staff", $company_id ,'Select Contact...', 'comp_staff', '', 'Select Contact...') . '<a href="#" id="con_add">Add Tag</a><br/>';

if($type === "Radio"){
    $output .= SelectBuilder::getDirectoryCompanyProgramme("comp_prog", $company_id, 'Select Programme...', 'comp_prog') . '<a href="#">Add Tag</a>';
}else{
    $output .= SelectBuilder::getDirectoryCompanyColumn("comp_cols", $company_id, 'Select Column...', 'comp_cols') . '<a href="#">Add Tag</a><br/>';
    $output .= SelectBuilder::getDirectoryCompanySupplement("comp_sups", $company_id, 'Select Supplement...', 'comp_sups') . '<a href="#">Add Tag</a>';
}

$output .= "</p>";

//Return the HTML
echo $output;
```

This adds up to three new dropdowns with the following `ids`

- comp_staff
- comp_prog
- comp_cols
- comp_sups

Each dropdown has an anchor tag after it with an id. I am trying to get a reference to this anchor tag so I can execute some code.

This is how I am currently trying to reference it:

```
$('#con_add').click(function(e){
            console.log('click');
            e.preventDefault();
            $companyName = $('#comp_staff option:selected').text();
            $companyId = $('#comp_staff option:selected').val();
            $type = 'contact';

            //Display Name of the Company
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $companyName);
            //Update Hidden Fields of Form
            $('#comp_name').val($companyName);
            $('#comp_id').val($companyId);
            $('#type').val('contact');

            //Make AJAX request to PHP file which will generate the Tags for the Object
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $companyName, 'id': $companyId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });
```

However, it is not working, and I think it must be because the anchor tag does not exist at the time of the page being loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: id attributes should be unique

Comment: Ya, IDs must be unique on document context and P element cannot contains a SELECT element (only phrasing elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing). Start fixing that then read how to delegate event for dynamic elements: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: All my id's are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Id must be unique, As A. WolF says your HTML is invalid *"P element cannot contains a SELECT element"*,  and you need to use event delegation like:

```
$(document).on('çlick', 'a', function(e){
            console.log('click');
            e.preventDefault();
            $companyName = $('#comp_staff option:selected').text();
            $companyId = $('#comp_staff option:selected').val();
            $type = 'contact';

            //Display Name of the Company
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $companyName);
            //Update Hidden Fields of Form
            $('#comp_name').val($companyName);
            $('#comp_id').val($companyId);
            $('#type').val('contact');

            //Make AJAX request to PHP file which will generate the Tags for the Object
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $companyName, 'id': $companyId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });
```

Comment: It should be noted too than OP's HTML markup isn't valid

Comment: I've taken on board what yourself and @A.Wolff have said and I've fixed the mark up, but I'm trying your suggested code and it is not working, I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Did you see the console? Any Error Here?